# How can I make Xcode autocomplete delegate methods?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

This code uses a delegate

```
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @ "Error" message: @ "You can leave the text blank" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @ "Quit" otherButtonTitles: @ "OK", nil] show];
```

The delegate in question is:

```
 (void) alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger) buttonIndex {
```

My question is this:
How do you autocomplete for Xcode delegate methods?.

In Eclipse you can do from the Source menu option Generate Delegate methods.

Regards and thanks!

Comment: Add <UIAlertViewDelegate> in the header file after @interface

Comment: Do you mean how do you generate all the relevant methods to the editor? Or how do you use the delegate methods?

Comment: generate all the relevant methods to the editor.

Comment: Instead of adding your solution to the question, you should write an answer. It's totally fine to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 7):

Your class should support UIAlertViewDelegate protocol

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject 
<
  UIAlertViewDelegate
>
```

start typing "dash" - you'll see all supported method included `UIAlertViewDelegate` methods. To reduce the autocomplete methods list: type `-alert`

Simply use "Go to definition" to see all "UIAlertViewDelegate" methods. Start typing one of the following methods in your `XCode`

[image]

If method under `@required` section you have to implement it in your delegate object otherwise you'll get warning.
If under `@optional` methods you don't have to implement any of these methods (you won't get warnings), but in most cases you should do this to let it work as you expect.

Comment: The line that read: `start typing "dash" - you'll see all supported method included UIAlertViewDelegate methods. To reduce the autocomplete methods list: type -alert` was MOST helpful to me! thank you so much, it made code completion a little easier whereas before I was trying to figure out the return type for delegate methods! not many tanks to you. Cheers.

Comment: injectios, now if only there was a way to automatically have xCode insert all the `@required` delegate methods in your view controller for you! ;)

Answer (score 3):

try press `esc` in keyboard, Xcode : Version 11.3.1 (11C504)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the method is **not** required, you won't get any warning about unimplemented methods.
XCode and Eclipse are different.

In second thought, u can use this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206500/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-in-xcode-to-add-a-delegates-or-protocols-method)

Comment: More properly, xCode is several years behind Eclipse, Android Studio/IntelliJ, et al in working with complex classes and autocompleting code, looking up usages, etc. (Well, AS missed a lot of usages whereas Eclipse never did). As of this comment about 4 years later xCode STILL does not have a feature to auto-insert stubs for all required methods. Apple. What a joke.

Answer (score 1):

Another choice, you can use appcode instead of xcode, "Generate" feature can be found.

Comment: You should add more details.

Comment: Appcode is definitively the best choice. It lets you add all available delegate methods from a protocol (optional or required) from a list and inserts them in your code. I can´t understand why that´s not a part of xcode or does´t exist as a plugin

Comment: @Tintenklecks There's a plugin in xcode, you can try it! https://github.com/music4kid/FastStub-Xcode

Comment: @cleexiang: thanks a lot. I wish I had known this one when I developed in objective c ... Unfortunately it's not for swift 

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode you can create your own class with the custom component as per your need and create a delegate methods in side that for responding like people uses for parsing and AsyncImageView and etc..

you can visit [here](http://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) for Async class demo with the respoct of this you can write your own class for `UIAlertView`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to all.

In this case all "@protocol UIAlertViewDelegate" methods are under @optional.I understand that in this case it is not necessary my class should support UIAlertViewDelegate protocol because all methods are under @optional.

The solutions is:

right-click on UIAlertViewDelegate or UIAlertView, click on "Jump to definition", then you can see the @protocol. Inside you can see methods with @optional and @requiered. If method under @required section you have to implement it in your delegate object otherwise you'll get warning. If under @optional methods you don't have to implement any of these methods (you won't get warnings)

Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do for delegates that I use frequently.

- Find the required methods and optional ones that you will always implement by accessing the UIAlertViewDelegate definition.
- Add empty implementations for these methods.
- Add a snippet with the shortcut being the delegate name and the content being my empty implementations (select then drag and drop to snippet library)
- Next time I use that delegate all I need to do is to start typing my shortcut (Ex: AlertViewDelegate to auto-insert my empty implementations

Bonus:

I also sometimes add in some default code in the implementations that is always going to be there, example:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSString* title = [alertView.title lowercaseString];
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        if ([title isEqualToString:<#action title#>]) {
            <#statements#>
        }
    }else{
        <#cancel code#>
    }
}
```